# How to address Model Names that are multiple words?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I am working on an Ember app in which some data is being posted to four different views.  The code below works for 3 views that have single word names(Local, Business,  Entertainment), but on my WorldNews view the data isn't loading.

In Chrome Ember Inspector, the WorldNews model is being called as world-news, so I'm not quite sure what I need to change in order to have the data be posted properly.

Data Info

```
App.WorldNews = DS.Model.extend({
    title: DS.attr('string'),
    post: DS.attr('string'),
    date: DS.attr('date')
});

App.WorldNews.FIXTURES = [
    {
        id: '1',
        title: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetu',
        post: 'asdf.',
        date: new Date('1-7-2041')
    }
]
```

Index / World News Template

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="worldnews">
            <h2>World News</h2>
            {{#each entries in model}}
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h3 class="panel-title" id="panel-title">{{entries.title}} - {{entries.date}}<a class="anchorjs-link" href="#panel-title"><span class="anchorjs-icon"></span></a></h3>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    {{entries.post}}
                </div>
            </div>
            {{/each}}
        </script>
```

Comment: Where do you run into issues? Everything you've posted so far should work - what about it doesn't?

Comment: Show as the route or ember inspector.